# 410 for specific non-existent subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In Google Webmaster Tools I get a lot of "strange" urls that have a 404.
I have no idea where they come from.
They always have subfolders that never existed and probably never will.
Here are some examples:

> https://example.com/{...}/plus.google.com/facebook.com/password-reset.hmlt/register.html
>   https://example.com/{...}/plus.google.com/facebook.com/facebook.com/password-reset.hmlt
>   https://example.com/{...}/plus.google.com/facebook.com/password-reset.hmlt/plus.google.com
>   https://example.com/{...}/register.html/facebook.com/password-reset.hmlt/register.html
>   https://example.com/{...}/password-reset.hmlt/register.html/plus.google.com/password-reset.hmlt
>
> ...

It seems its a random mix of these subfolders.
How can I produce a 410 for these urls utilising the htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block if the url contains any of the strings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} password-reset|register.html|plus.google.com
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410]
```

Block if the url contains `facebook.com and (plus.google.com or password-reset.hmlt)`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} facebook.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} plus.google.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} password-reset.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410]
```

(`[OR]` has higher precedence than the (implicit) `[AND]`)

Comment: hi thanks, that's working. but maybe my question is not clear enough? it is always a mix. so how can I for example say: if the url contains `facebook.com and (plus.google.com or password-reset.hmlt)` block it